# Zebra Printer Calibration

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using Zebra printer model ZQ520 and connecting to it through application in C#.

```
        string zpl = "^XA^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a ZPL test.^FS^XZ";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            string setLang = "! U1 setvar \"device.languages\" \"zpl\"\r\n";
            string calibrate = "~jc^xa^jus^xz\r\n";

            connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(setLang));
            connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(calibrate));
            connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(zpl));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:" + e.Message);
        }
```

The issue is the printer is printing out an excessive amount of paper. It doesn't print "This is a ZPL test." until I press the line feed button on the printer, and then it printer more excess paper after the desired message.

Any idea what issue might be?

Comment: What is `connection`? I had to use a Win(32?) api to directly connect to a Windows printer, so _how_ you're connecting definitely matters. (OS, device, etc.)

Comment: Have you calibrated it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the ^LL  (Label Length) command.  Look it up in your Zebra Programming Language guide.

I also know when I was doing Zebra (and also Intermec), the device itself had machine settings / display using buttons and arrows to change such default settings as page sizes, if thermal, what burn strength 0-30, etc., so you did not have to invoke those on every label submit.

I was also communicating directly with serial port using USB to RS232 connector cable, but it has been a while.

Comment: I tried using the ^LL command as well as `connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("! U1 setvar \"epl.media_type\" \"continuous\"\r\n"));
                connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("! U1 setvar \"zpl.label_length\" \"400\""));` but the same amount of paper prints out

Comment: Using `connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("! U1 setvar \"zpl.label_length\" \"400\""));` works to set the length of the label printed but it's still printing out an excessive amount of blank paper before it hits that point

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following code to communicate with the printer:

```
using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
{
    try
    {
        var ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        var printerPort = 9001;
        tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, printerPort);

        using (var tcpClientStream = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream()))
        {
            var deviceLang = "! U1 setvar \"device.languages\" \"zpl\"\r\n");
            tcpClientStream.Write(deviceLang );
            tcpClientStream.Flush();

            var calibrate = "~jc^xa^jus^xz";
            tcpClientStream.Write(calibrate);
            tcpClientStream.Flush();

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            string zpl = "^XA^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a ZPL test.^FS^XZ";
            // with ^LL: string zpl = "^XA^LL400^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a ZPL test.^FS^XZ";
            tcpClientStream.Write(zpl);
            tcpClientStream.Flush();

            tcpClientStream.Close();
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex); // replace with your own logger or console
    }
}
```

This should print the expected text immediately. Other than that, for continuous media (i.e. no gaps). I'm not familiar with this particular model but according to this:

https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Calibrating-Zebra-QLn-Series-Mobile-Printers?language=en_US

You need to send the following command: `! U1 setvar "media.type" "journal"` then set the label length somehow, for example `^LL400`.
Also you may try to comment the deviceLang and calibrate commands, not 100% sure those are really required (on the ZT610 they're definitely not, as you can calibrate the printer using buttons).

Comment: My guess is there's something wrong with the calibration because it's printing out the desired size for the actual label but it's printing an excessive amount of blank paper before getting to that. I actually have it working on a different printer (same model). I need this to work on multiple printers and I need to setup calibration through the code. Is there a way to reset the printer and then calibrate it properly?

Comment: Sending `^XA^JUF^XZ` before the other commands should restore factory settings. Then send `deviceLang` as above. Also you may try to print all settings on a printer that works and same on the one that doesn't, then compare. Not pleasant but may help. Also note `^LH` is retained until you turn off the printer or send another one, so you can also try `^LH0` to reset it just in case.